# Buttons not responding Scrollview- ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, scrollview

I have a custom scrollview that I added to a viewcontroller with buttons, textfields and slider.

I was having problems with the slider and the scrollview (the scrollview was not scrolling) until I added :

```
scroll.m

 scrollView.canCancelContentTouches=NO;
        scrollView.delaysContentTouches=NO;

- (BOOL)touchesShouldBegin:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event inContentView:(UIView *)view {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:view];
        CGRect thumbRect;
        UISlider *mySlide = (UISlider*) view;
        CGRect trackRect = [mySlide trackRectForBounds:mySlide.bounds];
        thumbRect = [mySlide thumbRectForBounds:mySlide.bounds trackRect:trackRect value:mySlide.value];
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(thumbRect, location))
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Now it is scrolling but the buttons and textfields on the scrollview no longer respond to the touch events. I've tried some solutions from this site:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (self.scrollView.superview != nil) {
        if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            return NO; // ignore the touch
        }
return YES;
```

}

No luck with the buttons. Any suggestions? Thanks.

**update**

I put an NSLog in the buttons' target actions and they are not being called. is this a delegate issue not a touch event issue?

Comment: sounds like ur buttons are behind your scroll view layer.

check your story board?

Comment: The buttons were added programatically to the scrollview

Comment: yea, thats the issue adding stuff programatically. You might have to play with the layout ordering and stuff so the componenents get drawn properly.

Comment: This fixed the textfields but the button actions aren't being seen by the scrollview.